# Inserting objects in MongoDB to field that can reference two different objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

In my project I have a Messages model that looks like this:

```
var MessageSchema = new Schema({
fromId: {
    type: entityId,
    required: true
},
toId: {
    type: entityId,
    required: true
},
important: {
    type: Boolean, 
    required: false
},
lessonId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: Models.Lesson,
    required: false
},
memberId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: Models.Lesson,
    required: false
},
message: {
    type: String, 
    required: true
}});
```

As long as a message can be sent and received either by User and School I've created a complex type 'entityId' that looks like this:

```
var entityId = {
id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
},
entityName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: entityTypeList.array
}};
```

and I'm putting this as a 'type' in the fields fromId and toId in my MessageSchema (as shown above). Now, when I try to insert entities like that one:

```
    sampleMessage1: {
    _id:"560e9504cac9a42f0e415bca",
    memberId: "5631f6883ad9bc561889f006",
    deleted:true,
    fromId:
        {
            entityName:"school",
            id:"55d1e957daea17d3e90a3c51"
        },
    toId:
        {
            entityName:"user",
            id:"569b89bb90d3ccd06d96644b"
        },
    important:false,
    message:"Sample message.",
    messageType:"notification",
    read:true,
    timestamp:"2015-07-31T16:11:32.714Z"
}
```

using 'schema.create', in the 'id' field, in database both in fromId and toId, instead of ObjectId I get String. I know that I can do something like this:

```
id: new ObjectId(55d1e957daea17d3e90a3c51")
```

but I wonder if there's another solution where I don't have to change my sample messages and can I do something I showed without using any 'ref:'?

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting entities? If you are doing `Message.insert(data)` then you are overriding mongoose. Try to create message first

```
var message = new Message(data);
message.save();
```

Comment: I'm using schema.create. I've tried message.insert() and message.save() but it doesn't work either. Can I skip 'ref' property in case where the field can reference documents from two different schemas?

Comment: I'm not sure then. I know you can make a  call to populate and explicitly set the model.

.populate({ path: 'fromId.id', model: fromId.entityName }); 

Maybe that can help?